# Android Firebase Copy Multiple Children

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am asking about a problem I have developing an app. My objective is to copy a child that contains other children to a different directory. The reason I need to do this is because on the start of my activity I want to get all of the posts that a user's friend has made. My problem is that using setValue I cant copy multiple friends posts as this will delete the other posts. My code,

```
 for (int i = 0; i<budsList.size();i++){
            feedRef.child(current_user_id).setValue(dataSnapshot.child(budsList.get(i)).getValue());
        }
```

Here budslist is a list of the user's friends, I am cycling through each friend and then grabbing their all posts from a different directory and adding them to a feed directory. Problem is when I do this with more than one friend it will cancel out the last data provided by the previous friend in the loop, leaving me with one user's post in the end. Any ideas? Thanks for any Answers.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful if you include what your database looks like.  What is the source data?  What do you want the destination data to look like after it's copied?

Comment: Sure, gimme a sec

Comment: Ok, got the firebase structure

Comment: Have you got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use  `updateChildren()` instead of `setValue()`. Here is the docs [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields).

Your code will look like this,

```
HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i<budsList.size();i++){
    map.put(dataSnapshot.child(budsList.get(i)).getKey(),dataSnapshot.child(budsList.get(i)).getValue());
}
feedRef.child(current_user_id).updateChildren(map);
```

Comment: Thanks very much!